# How can I create a foreign key constraint using Yesod/Persistent?

Tags: postgresql, migration, yesod, persistent

Is there a way to create a foreign key constraint using Persistent's schema syntax with the Postgres backend? Or do I need to do this manually with SQL? Specifically, an `ON DELETE CASCADE` relationship such that when a `HackDay` is deleted, all of its child `Project`s are deleted:

```
HackDay
    title Text
    created UTCTime default=now()
    votingClosed Bool default=false
    deriving Show
Project
    hackday HackDayId
    title Text
    creators Text
    votes Int default=0
    created UTCTime default=now()
    deriving Show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistent does not currently have any built-in support for triggers, though it's something we've been wanting to add (simply lacking manpower). For now, you'll have to add the trigger manually.